# determine slide down gesture on an image/button in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

Ionic has pull to refresh feature so far.

However, I would like to pull an image/button at top of the screen and do something when its pulled down.

How can I get this gesture of pull down on an image in ionic?

Comment: do these help ? http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onDragDown/
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onSwipeDown/

Comment: But that's specific to button. Is that going to work with image? or there a way to kind of hide the button with an image?

Comment: Not specific to any particular element. You can try it on image. Still you can style a button as image , pretty easy stuff.

Comment: Helped and solved. Done :) Thanks a lot for keeping up